# How to evaluate text strings provided by sed/grep/whatever?

Tags: string, sed, unix, sh

This is for UNIX shell programming.  It have to be supported by multiple UNIX platforms including Solaris, Linux, and AIX.

I have this scenario -- I am to read from a text file a string that may or may not contain an environment variable that may or may not be defined.  For example:

```
<foo.bar> This error code was found: $(error_code)
```

I have the following code:

```
statement=$(sed -n $1'p' $messagefile)
echo $echo_flag $statement
```

$1 = line number supplied to this particular function/script.
$messagefile = filename of log file.
$echo_flag = "-e" in Linux, otherwise, empty.
$(error_code) = 42.

Instead of getting this when running:

```
<foo.bar> This error code was found: 42
```

I still get this:

```
<foo.bar> This error code was found: $(error_code)
```

How exactly do I tell the shell script that the value of statement should be evaluated further beyond what sed have done?

Comment: I have read three times but I have to say I've not understand what you say.

Answer (score 1):

It's unfortunate that the input text uses $(error_code) as the syntax, because that looks like process substitution to the shell. "eval" is closer to what you want, bu it's also a security risk to take user-controlled input and execute it directly.

This error code was found: rm -rf /

What you'd need to do is parse the input line for the expected syntax and process the "error_code" token by itself, test for an in-scope shellvar, print modified output etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that I understand what you're asking, but would changing the `echo` command to `eval echo $echo_flag $statement` do what you want?

Comment: The only problem with that is that `$(error_code)` looks like command substitution instead of a variable and will produce an error. Further parsing would need to be done before you could do an `eval`.